# ThreeJs rendering issue

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have an application developed using ThreeJs. I am getting blank window after 3d rendering but if I click on full screen or adjust the window size i can see the output.

Screen shot 1: http://ghar360.com/ideas/media/issue-with-output

Screen shot 2: (desired output)   http://ghar360.com/ideas/media/desired-output

This issue started when I moved to new version of ThreeJs ( r57 to r69)

Comment: you really are not posting enough information to help you debug your problem. At least you know your resize function is firing and draws what you want so you should start from there and work backwards.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without looking at your code, but very likely you must call your onResize function manually to trigger scene/canvas init.

Answer (score -1):

This is the only help i can give you with your information given.
add `windowresize()`function

```
    window.addEventListener('resize', onWindowResize, false);
        function onWindowResize() {
              renderer.setSize(container.offsetWidth, window.innerHeight);
              _camera.aspect = container.offsetWidth / window.innerHeight;
              _camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

}
```